# how to wrap text after symbol

Tags: jquery, html

I have this line of text

```
<p>"May you live all the days of your life." — Jonathan Swift</p>
```

how to wrap this part "— Jonathan Swift" in span, so the result will be like:

```
<p>"May you live all the days of your life." <span>— Jonathan Swift</span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** with **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-function)** method.

```js
$('p').html(function(i, v) {
  return v.replace(/\—.*$/, '<span>$&</span>')
});
```

```css
p span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>"May you live all the days of your life." — Jonathan Swift</p>
```

Or using **[`String#substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)** method.

```js
$('p').html(function(i, v) {
  var ind = v.indexOf('—');
  return v.substr(0, ind) + '<span>' + v.substr(ind) + '</span>';
});
```

```css
p span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>"May you live all the days of your life." — Jonathan Swift</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about putting a `<br />` tag inside of your `<p>` tag? The resulting code would be:

```
<p>"May you live all the days of your life." <br />— Jonathan Swift</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text inside your `<p>` tags is always formatted in that same exact way (if they all end with the `— Author Name` at the end) then you can do something like this with JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p').each(function () {
    var orgText = $(this).html();
    var spanText = orgText.substring(0, (orgText.indexOf('—') -1)) + '<span>' + orgText.substring(orgText.indexOf('—'), orgText.length) + '</span>';

    $(this).html(spanText);
  });
});
```

WARNING: this solution assumes that no other `—` will be found inside the quote text.

See my jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/cL9qgnms/